# create a string from a structure array in c

Tags: c, arrays, string, structure

I'm new to c programming and I'm having a tough time figuring out how to create a string from a structure array.  I have a bunch of data points that I want to have in the program.  I created a structure array and now I need them to create a string from it. here is the code I have so far.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>

int main()
{ 
 int i=0;


      struct wmm
   {
    float n;
    float m;
    float gnm;
    float hnm;
    float dgnm;
    float dhnm;
   }  book[3]= {{1, 0,  -29496.6,       0.0,       11.6,       0.0},
  {1, 1,   -1586.3,    4944.4,       16.5,     -25.9},
  {2, 0,   -2396.6,       0.0,      -12.1,       0.0},
  {2, 1,    3026.1,   -2707.7,       -4.4,     -22.5}};
```

Now I would like to create a string called c_string and be able to use this function:

sscanf(c_str,"%d%d%lf%lf%lf%lf",&n,&m,&gnm,&hnm,&dgnm,&dhnm);

and use the list of data points for computations.

Thank you

Comment: In your example the data is already in the array, so why use sscanf?

Comment: I'm modifying a code that imported the data from a separate file but I need to have all of the data self contained in the program. In order to make as few alterations as possible I just wanted to produce a string that was exactly like the string that the program created from the data file.

Comment: You are trying to do code generation? If so, don't feel that you have to use c just because the code being generated is c. Other languages might be easier.

Answer (score 3):

You probably want to use `snprintf()` to do the formatted string generation, and `malloc()` to create a character array to write into.  Note that you may need to think carefully about large you need your character array to be.